# Google Spreadsheet + Apps: Get max value of column, it gives me date format

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use HTML and JS to write into a Spreadsheet and I found some useful code to do that. I had to add a column to insert an ID for each entry and I did it like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myKey").getSheetByName('Richieste');
var column = 1; 
var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, colArray);
var id = maxi+1;

// set other params

var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, area, text, ans, flag];
var sheetObj = sheet.appendRow(vals);
```

Now, if I have an empty sheet, it works for the first two entries: the third ID is set such as `02/01/1900 0.00.00` [and you can see a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDKTP.jpg).

I cannot understand what's going on... do you know something about this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the information you provided, but it looks like your cell format is set to date time, not a number.

Comment: I don't know what happened but I checked three times the type of data before I wrote here... how embarrassing...